GoogleImageCrawler only downloads 1 image while BingImageCrawler works fine in iCrawler
I’m using iCrawler to create a CLI-based tool for downloading images from Google and Bing. While the BingImageCrawler works perfectly and downloads the requested number of images, the GoogleImageCrawler only downloads 1 image, even when I specify a higher number (max_num).
Here’s My Setup:
1.  Environment:
•   Python version: (e.g., Python 3.10)
•   iCrawler version: (e.g., 0.6.5)
2.  Code Snippet:

from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler, BingImageCrawler

def download_images(search_term, num_images, source_choice, size, file_type, download_folder):
    if source_choice == '1':  # Google
        crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(storage={'root_dir': download_folder})
    elif source_choice == '2':  # Bing
        crawler = BingImageCrawler(storage={'root_dir': download_folder})

    filters = {'size': size, 'type': file_type}

    # Start crawling
    crawler.crawl(keyword=search_term, max_num=num_images, filters=filters)

3.  Inputs:
•   Search Term: “example”
•   Number of Images: 10
•   Source: Google
•   Size: “large”
•   File Type: “photo”
4.  What Works:
•   When using BingImageCrawler, the correct number of images are downloaded.
•   GoogleImageCrawler does successfully download 1 image but stops.
5.  What I’ve Tried:
•   Verified the filters parameter matches the documentation.
•   Tested with different max_num values (e.g., 5, 10, 20).
•   Checked the Google terms of service to ensure I’m not hitting API rate limits or bot detection.
•   Verified that the download_folder is writable and has sufficient space.
6.  Questions:
•   Is there a limitation or known issue with GoogleImageCrawler when handling larger batches of images?
•   Could this be caused by Google’s bot detection system?
•   Are there specific debugging steps I can take to trace why only 1 image is downloaded?k

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I tried using GoogleImageCrawler with specific filters (size, file type) and set max_num to download multiple images. I was expecting it to download the requested number of images (e.g., 10), but it only downloads 1 image regardless of the specified max_num.
